# Make local HTTP server inaccessable from outside

Tags: c, linux, http, networking, server

I want to write a program with HTTP server functionality on my Linux machine so that it can interact with my browser for showing formatted output etc.

After some research I decided to go with  [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/). A very basic server is quite easy to implement with this library. Based on the [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html), the following code already does the trick.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <microhttpd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 8888

static int
answer_to_connection(void *cls, struct MHD_Connection *connection,
                     const char *url, const char *method,
                     const char *version, const char *upload_data,
                     size_t *upload_data_size, void **con_cls)
{
  const char *page = "<html><body>Hello, browser!</body></html>";
  struct MHD_Response *response;
  int ret;
  response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page), (void*)page,                              
                                             MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
  ret = MHD_queue_response(connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
  MHD_destroy_response(response);
  return ret;
}


int main()
{
  struct MHD_Daemon *daemon;    
  daemon = MHD_start_daemon(MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY, PORT, NULL, NULL,
                            &answer_to_connection, NULL, MHD_OPTION_END);
  if (NULL == daemon) return 1;
  (void)getchar();
  MHD_stop_daemon(daemon);
  return 0;
}
```

Now my problem is that I do not know how to *make sure that I do not accidentally expose any of my data over the network* by running this server and letting it serve real data. I am not very experienced with network programming and it was hard for me to find explicit information on that in this context.

So to be more precise, my **Question**: Do I have to change something in the above program/on my system/in my router for making sure that the open port 8888 is only visible and accessable from localhost?

**Note:** Accomplishing this with libmicrohttpd would be nice, but not strictly necessary. If another approach/library is more secure, I am ready to give it a try.

Comment: Use iptables to block the port except to localhost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `MHD_OPTION_SOCK_ADDR` to bind to only `INADDR_LOOPBACK`. This will make sure you do not listen on anything other than the loopback address and will guarantee, no external machine can connect.

The modified code looks something like following

```
int main()
{
    struct MHD_Daemon *daemon;
    struct sockaddr_in loopback_addr;

    memset(&loopback_addr, 0, sizeof(loopback_addr));
    loopback_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    loopback_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    loopback_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);

    daemon = MHD_start_daemon(MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY,
                        PORT,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        &answer_to_connection,
                        NULL,
                        MHD_OPTION_SOCK_ADDR, (struct sockaddr *)(&loopback_addr),
                        MHD_OPTION_END);

    if (daemon == NULL) return 1;
    (void)getchar();
    MHD_stop_daemon(daemon);
   return 0;
}
```

Also `man bind` would help to find out about binding to an address to listen to.

You can test this by running `netstat -ln -tcp` after running the server.

Answer (score -1):

As @stark commented, adopt unix spirit "small and different tools that handle tasks perfectly" : use webserver to handle http request, use firewall such as iptables or new nftables to protect your server from outside

Answer (score -2):

For simplicity, IP address  specifies the computer in the Internet and the port(such as 8888,80,etc) will determine which applications you want to visit in one computer.
In general, IP addresses are divided into two categories： public and private. You need to pay if you want to get a public IP address(such as 202.117.21.116), and then your machine and applications will be found in Internet. your machine will not be found directly in the Internet if you have a private IP address(such as 192.168.*.* or 127.*.*.*,etc). I think your IP address is private and your data  will never expose to others in Internet but your HTTP server application will be found by the ones in the local area network if they know your IP address and your HTTP server port(8888). Although your machine will be found in the local area network, they are just  allowed to visit the data that you specify in your HTTP server instead of all data in your machine.
So you can use the localhost to visit your application, and the others in the local area network only get the data----"Hello, browser!" that you specified in your program, and the others in Internet can not access your machine.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps. But I am particularly concerned with the data the server will send. Can I make the port inaccessable for other machines on the local network, too, without external programs like iptables?

Comment: Sorry to reply so later, I am a little busy recently. In your sever,you can check the information of the connected clients  and then decide who can receive your data.  You can make the rule in your server before you send the data to the clients.For example,the clients should seed the password or some words to prove he is a legal client. After you check the information from the client,  you can send the data.